# adb doesn't detect my Defy (Motorola MB525) after I call adb kill-server (rageagainstthecage exploit). Any ideas?

Tags: rooting, adb, motorola-defy

I'm trying [cyanogen's mod approach](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Motorola_Defy%3a_Full_Update_Guide) to root my Defy. I **can** do `adb shell`, it works as intended. But after I run `adb kill-server` and try an `adb shell` I get

```
error: device not found
```

It seems my phone just decides to not be connected anymore when I call `kill-server`. I need to **physically** reboot it and start everything again.

This is the complete command session I did:

```
[~]$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
0A3AA8D5195599849BN device

[~]$ adb shell      
$ exit
[~]$ adb kill-server
[~]$ adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
[~]$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

[~]$ adb shell
error: device not found
[~]$
```

This is driving me nuts. I've searched about this problem, but there simply isn't a solution in entire Google's database. I want to use this rageagainstthecage root approach because I can see the exploit source, I'm a little nervous about using something in my personal phone that I don't know what it does (an explanation about [rageagainstthecage](http://dtors.org/2010/08/25/reversing-latest-exploid-release/), and a [compact explanation](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?s=3c89f640fb6d394672ee491d650461bb&p=12356909&postcount=4))...

Anyone here at SE network have seen a similar problem - or have a suggestion?

I'm doing this in a Macbook Pro machine (OS X 10.6.8). My phone has Android 2.2.1.

(PS: Even without using the exploit, just doing `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server`, my cell phone isn't shown anymore on `adb devices`, thus receiving `error: device not found`. So this seens to be a problem with `adb kill-server`)

Comment: do adb start-server after killing it.

Comment: Instead of doing kill-server, try going in to Settings -> Applications -> Development and turn off USB Debugging, then turn it back on

Comment: @PadmaKumar When you run `adb devices`, it automatically starts the server. So, if you try to run `adb start-server` before doens't matter, you receive the same `error: device not found`.

Comment: @RyanConrad this doesn't work either... Even if I remove the usb cable, it doesn't detect after I call `adb kill-server`. I have to physically reboot my phone. :/

Comment: I missed this before that you have the motorolla defy. This runs BLUR and I have always had a hard time getting adb to find a BLUR device. I had to switch the different USB modes to get it to find it.

Comment: @RyanConrad The problem is: it finds my phone. BUT if i call `adb kill-server` it stops seeing it. I don't think is a problem with the usb modes, since what I need to be able to use `adb` is check on debugging mode... but I'm going to try your suggestion.

Comment: I'm developing android apps for 2 years with a MB525 as main testing device. The USB connection of that device is so flawed its unbelievable. I think the main problem is the 4 different USB modes you can choose. and also defy only looks for ADB once. You can try to switch USB modes after you kill your servers, maybe then it will find it agai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem (Rom: 34.177.3.MB525.Retail.en.DE). The only rooting method that worked was Gingerbreak ( http://project89.com/root-defy-without-pc-gingerbreak-200/ )

Comment: Well, thanks for answering about another exploit working. I believe SuperOneClick used gingerbreak as well, since it uses a lot of different exploits to accomplish the root goals.

Answer (score 2):

i'm late to the party but in case anyone googles this and finds it - my own experience of this is solved if you perform the rooting without an SD card in the phone

that way windows doesn't mount the phone and get in the way

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same setup and problems described by @"Somebody still uses you MS-DOS". I'm using a mac 10.6 and trying to root Motorola Defy following the [Cyanogen's](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Motorola_Defy%3a_Full_Update_Guide#Rooting_the_Motorola_Defy) wiki and using rageagainstthecage to root.

The wiki suggests using "psneuter" to gain root. Instruction below come from the [RootzWiki](http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Motorola_Defy#Gain_Root).

Download latest version of psneuter, and extract. Then run the following ADB commands

```
./adb push ${LOCATION_OF_PSNEUTER_BINARY}/psneuter /data/local/temp/psneuter
./adb shell
chmod 755 /data/local/temp/psneuter
./data/local/temp/psneuter
```

ADB should hang, wait a while and then type

```
./adb shell
```

If you see a '#' sign instead of the '$' then you have temporary root.

Comment: Hum, I believe the psneuter wasn't available as an option when I read the wiki. Thanks for this information, it might be helpful for someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try running `adb start-server` using `sudo`.

On my ubuntu machine that I use as my test environment, I always need to start adb service using root.

Comment: This isn't a problem with Mac OS X, since I already run these commands and can use them without problem (they're installed using homebrew), but thanks anyway. (I've already come across this hint about `sudo` on http://www.pocketmagic.net/?p=762)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer to this question, but to the exploit itself: I just became fed up after two days of suffering. I used a tool named [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/?p=155) and in 10s it rooted my phone.